How to get the range with correct value in google script
need take this range Sheet in 2D Array

my Code is
var baseNumArr = baseNumSheet.getRange ('C2:E').getValues();
  Logger.log (baseNumArr);

And result:

[[5.76375343E8, 20.0, Заменяющ.], [5.75696005E8, 400.0, Заменяющ.], [9.75696E8, 40.0, Заменяющ.], [, 50.0, ], [3.71333333E8, 70.0, Заменяющ.], [, , Заменяющ.], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, ,

Help please, need:

baseNumArr [[0][0,1,2,...]] convert to String, need result like that - 576375343 in baseNumArr[[0][0]]
as a result, there should be no empty strings in the 2D-array, only those with values   (need delete from 2D-array [, , ], [, , ], [, , ],)


Have you tried to use .getRange() var baseNumArr = sheet.getRange('C2:E6').getValues();. let me know if this works for you. -
Updated comment.

How .getRange() works
sheet.getLastRow()


Returns the position of the last row that has content.

getRange(row, column)


Returns the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates.

getRange(2, 3, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3)

gets all rows from columns C to E starting from row 2.
.getValues()

Retrieve Values: The .getValues() method retrieves the values from the specified range and stores them in a 2D array.
In this case, it will return a 2D array where:

Each row in the 2D array corresponds to a row from the spreadsheet (rows 2 to 6).
Each column in the 2D array corresponds to the values in columns C, D, and E.

Modified code into.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 3, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3); 
var baseNumArr = dataRange.getValues();

baseNumArr = baseNumArr.filter(function(row) {
  return row.some(function(cell) {
    return cell !== ""; 
  });
});

Logger.log(baseNumArr);

filter removes rows where all cells are empty.
row.some checks if any cell in the row is not empty.
This will give you only the non-empty rows for further processing.
Reference

getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)


and if the exact number of lines is not known and can change?
I planned to take all the lines and delete the empty ones

I’ve updated my answer above. Please let me know if it provides the clarification you were looking for.
